# Semigroup $S$ problem

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

A semigroup is a set $S$ with an associative operation, which we will write as multiplication. That is, $x(yz) = (xy)z$ for all $x, y, z \in S$.

a) Suppose that a finite semigroup $S$ has the property that for all $x$ there is an integer $n > 1$ such that $x^n = x$. Is it true that $S$ is, in fact, a group?

b) Suppose that a finite semigroup $S$ has the property that for all $x$ there is an integer $n$ such that $x^{n+1} = x^n$. Show that the only subsets of $S$ which form a group are of size $1$.

I am interested in how people answer this question. I am having difficulty myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to (a) is negative. Take the semigroup $\{1,a,a^2\}$ with $a^3 = a$ (and hence $a^4 = a^2$).

Answer to (b) is a bit more difficult. Let $G$ be a subset of $S$ forming a group and let $e$ be the identity of this group. Let $x \in G$ and let $n > 0$ be such that $x^{n+1} = x^n$. Since $G$ is a finite group, we also have $x^{|G|} = e$, whence $x^{n|G|} = e$. Now $x^{n|G|} = x^{n|G|+1}$, that is $e = ex = x$. Thus $G$ is trivial.

The class of finite semigroups defined by your property are called [*aperiodic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_semigroup).

Comment: In your answer to part (a), why isn't $\{1,a,a^2\}$ a group? Is it because it does not contain an inverse i.e. $x^{-1}\notin S$.

Comment: What would be the inverse of $a$?

Comment: Inverse of $a$ would be $\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{a}\notin S=\{1,a,a^2\}$ then $S$ is not a group. Is this correct?

Comment: More precisely $1 \over a$ does not make sense in $S$.

Comment: Why would it not make sense?